# ajax request is not returning back to view in laravel 5

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I wanted to submit a for using ajax call in laravel 5.

In view i wrote something like

```
$("#updateSubmit").on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");
$.ajax({
            method:'POST',
            url: '/account/updateForm',
            //dataType: 'json',
            data: {accountId:'1111', _token:   '{{csrf_token()}}'}, 
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert(data)
                    return false;
                }
            },
    error: function(error ){
      alert("There is some error");
    }
});
```

and on controller side

```
public function update(Request $data )
{
    return Response()->json(['success' => true],200);
}
```

while in route for post method

```
 Route::post('account/updateForm', 'AccountController@update')->name('account/updateForm');
```

its working till ajax. on Submission of ajax it goes to controller action.
but it does not retrun back as ajax comes back in normal form submisson.

it just go to controller and stops there with {"success":true} line.

I want ajax to come back to view form so that I can perform different dependent actions.

Comment: means from backend you want View Page and that should return in ajax call, am i right ?

Comment: yes in short, from back end it should come to same page, because I want to send  some validation kind of things from backend and in ajax success am creating those errors to show

Comment: RnD on ViewToString concept may be it can help you, actually i not laravel developer but in c# MVC for this kind of logic, I pass the data to View and then convert View page to string and then i pass this data to json

Comment: actually in previous laravel version such simple logic used to work. Dont know what is wrong here.

Comment: Finally solved this issue.
I was using same form for add and update.
So I had used form with model and open section and had provided controllers methods to actions. So it was going to that by default and ajax was not performing 
and another silly mistake I had done is I had called on button submit action.

So it was going to action and stopping there only.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that when you submit your form, you just have a white page with `{"success": true}` ?

If that's the case, maybe the error is on your javascript.

Maybe your jQuery selector is wrong, or maybe your js isn't compiled ?